# Reading from one socket for several consumers asynchronously in one thread

Tags: c++, asynchronous, networking, boost-asio, fibers

I am implementing a connection multiplexer - class, which wraps a single connection in order to provide an ability to create so-called `Stream`-s over it. There can be dozens of such streams over one physical connection.

Messages sent over that connection are defined by a protocol and can be service ones (congestion control, etc), which are never seen by the clients, and data ones - they contain some data for the streams, for which one - defined in the header of the corresponding message.

I have encountered a problem when implementing a method `read` for a `Stream`. It must be blocking, but asynchronous, so that it returns some value - data read or error happened - but the request itself must be is some kind of async queue.

To implement asynchronous network IO we have used Boost's `async_read`-s, `async_write`-s, etc with a completion token, taken from another library. So, a call to `MyConnection::underlying_connection::read(size_t)` is asynchronous already in the terms I described before.

One solution I have implemented is function `MyConnection::processFrame()`, which is reading from the connection, processing message and, if it is a data message, puts the data into the corresponding stream's buffer. The function is to be called in a `while` loop by the stream's `read`. But, in that case there can be more than one simulteneous calls to `async_read`, which is UB. Also, this would mean that even service messages are to wait until some stream wants to read the data, which is not appropriate as well.

Another solution I came up is using `future`-s, but as I checked, their methods `wait/get` would block the whole thread (even with defered policy or paired promise), which must be avoided too.

Below is a simplified example with only methods, which are needed to understand the question. This is current implementation, which contains bugs.

```cpp
struct LowLevelConnection {
  /// completion token of 3-rd part library - ufibers
  yield_t yield;

  /// boost::asio socket
  TcpSocket socket_;

  /// completely async (in one thread) method
  std::vector<uint8_t> read(size_t bytes) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> res;
    res.reserve(bytes);

    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, res, yield);

    return res;
  }
}

struct MyConnection {
  /// header is always of that length
  constexpr uint32_t kHeaderSize = 12; 

  /// underlying connection
  LowLevelConnection connection_;

  /// is running all the time the connection is up
  void readLoop() {
    while (connection_.isActive()) {
      auto msg = connection_.read(kHeaderSize);
      if (msg.type == SERVICE) { handleService(msg); return; }

      // this is data message; read another part of it
      auto data = connection_.read(msg.data_size);

      // put the data into the stream's buffer
      streams_.find(data.stream_id).buffer.put(data);
    }
  }
}

struct Stream {
  Buffer buffer;

  // also async blocking method
  std::vector<uint8_t> read(uint32_t bytes) {
    // in perfect scenario, this should look like this
    async_wait([]() { return buffer.size() >= bytes; });

    // return the subbuffer of 'bytes' size and remove them
    return subbufer...
  }
}
```

Thanks for future answers!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the requirements for the interface you provide, "blocking, but asynchronous" is not clear. Does the code using the streams use callbacks/coroutines/fibers/? Also, who manages the executors / fibers in your scenario?

Comment: "blocking, but asynchronous" doesn't make much sense, lookup like a conyradiction in terms.

Comment: @Zulan. By "blocking, but asynchronous" I mean that you call the method, it returns some value directly, without callbacks, etc, but under the hood, it uses fibers to manage multitasking - so there are no threads created, but the one thread still does not get blocked, even if there is no value to return yet - just switch to another task. Executors/fibers are managed by the underlying implementation of `LowLevelConnection` - when a new connection arrives from "the other side", it gets wrapped into a fiber. If we open a connection, again, it's opened inside a fiber